# understanding resolv.conf nameserver through system calls

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, socket

I am trying to understand how /etc/resolv.conf /etc/nsswitch.conf exactly works and what is significance of nameserver entry 127.0.1.1

I did strace ping google.com to get to know about the system calls involved , one part is :

```
stat64("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=172, ...}) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.1.1")}, 16) = 0
gettimeofday({1413780874, 913366}, NULL) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
send(4, "\0040\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\6google\3com\0\0\1\0\1", 28, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 28
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(4, FIONREAD, [204])               = 0
recvfrom(4, "\0040\201\200\0\1\0\v\0\0\0\0\6google\3com\0\0\1\0\1\300\f\0\1"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.1.1")}, [16]) = 204
close(4)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("173.194.123.36")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(58830), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.13")}, [16]) = 0
close(4)
```

can any one please explain what is going on here ? specially connect on 127.0.1.1 as it is namsserver entry in my resolv.conf Why we need to make socket connection to 127.0.1.1 ? and how do we get response from it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your `resolv.conf` includes `nameserver 127.0.1.1`.

When pinging `google.com` in your example this name first needs to be looked up so that `ping` knows an IP address which it can send the ICMP echo request packets to.

To find the IP address it consults the configured nameserver, hence why it communicates with `127.0.1.1` on `53/udp`.

Comment: alright, how nameserver is confiugured, and which process exactly responds to this request , if it is localhost then why it is not 127.0.0.1? I mean I am using fresh ubuntu installation so how 127.0.1.1 is set up as nameserver ?

Comment: @Ameyj `127/8` is reserved for loopback, `127.0.0.1` is just the first loopback address. You can investigate which process has bound to 127.0.1.1 53 using for instance `netstat -plnut` or `lsof`. As for why Ubuntu have set things up this way I think you will have to check their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is still a IP so it makes a socket connection for UDP to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: can you elaborate more ? 127.0.1.1 is one of host in /etc/hosts , why socket connection is made to 127.0.1.1

Comment: what does your /etc/resolv.conf look like?

Comment: nameserver 127.0.1.1

Answer (score 0):

First, the existance of /etc/resolv.conf is checked with `stat()`.
Second, the socket for the resolving is prepared with `socket()`.
Then this socket is initialized with `connect()` to the IP address of the resolver, udp protocol and port number 53. Then the request is sent with `send()` and the reply is read with `recvfrom()`. Then the socket is closed with `close()`.